How to take a square photo with flutter
I am using camera package, and I want to make a square preview of camera when I take the image that should also be square.
Current code :
return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: CameraPreview(
          controller!,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) =>
                  onViewFinderTap(details, constraints),
            );
          }),
        ),
      )

It is showing square preview, but it making it look elongated and also when I take image it is not even square.
